# How to override Drawer in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my component I need to override css parameter "overflow-y". This parameter is described in class .MuiDrawer-paper. 
Usually to override css is piece of cake via makeStyles. But in this component has two divs. Parent container and daughter div. And when I set overrided class like:

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      paper: {
        overflowY: 'unset',
      },
    )};
```

...

```
className={classes.paper}
```

Parent div gets this class and it does not have any sense. Because I need to override daughter class.
I tried to do some thing like this:

```
 className={{ paper: classes.paper }}
```

But in this case class wan't picked... What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to override material ui classes is to make use of `classes` [prop](https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/#props) on `Drawer` component instead of `className`.

[Read more about overriding classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes)

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      paper: {
        overflowY: 'unset',
      },
    )};
...
     <Drawer
        classes={{
          paper: classes.paper,
        }}
        anchor="left"
        open={open}        
     />
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped. I tried it before but I skipped that I had another request to this property. Final version looks like that:

Comment: classes={{
        paper: clsx(classes.paper, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
        }),
      }}

Comment: `useStyles` is not referenced anywhere... `makeStyles` is not defined... and the link provided does not show an example of using the `classes={{...}}` prop. Maybe update this answer?

Answer (score 0):

The top-voted answer in this thread contains legacy code (`makeStyles`). I was able to override CSS on a child element of a MUI component via the `styled` API ([migration guide](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#1-use-styled-or-sx-api)):

```
const StyledMUIComponent = styled(MUIComponentName)({
  "& .child-class-to-target": {
    overflowY: 'unset'
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I have 2 options.

1. using `!important`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    overflowY: 'unset !important',
  },
)};
```

2. using `styles` property.

```
<Drawer style={{overflowY: 'unset'}} />
```

I prefer to use `styles` property.